# Category does not exists in rows: 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125... Problem in importing products in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, magento-1.9.2.1

I tried to import product from import/export. I got an error `Category does not exists in rows: 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125`...

What i did was :

1. Checked uppercase, lowercase, whitespace from `_category` column
2. Checked backend categories. They do exists.
3. If i place a single category to every product. No error.

What can be the possible solution for this issue. Please suggest.
Thanks.